# default event add/remove implementation

Tags: c#, .net, events, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I'm looking to implement some extra logic when event handlers are added or removed to an event.

I'm aware that the default implementation in .net changed recently.

I'd like to keep my implementation as close to the default implementation as possible.

Can anyone point me to/provide something that shows how the compliler implements events?

Comment: sorry, it's not clear what you're asking for .. how can implement something "like compiler" does it?

Comment: The compiler performs magic to implement events. I'd like to know how that "magic" translates to code that can be implemented in the `add`/`remove` handlers that *can be implemented in code*.

Comment: It isn't magic; it's just complicated.

Comment: I might have to invoke Clarke's 3rd Law

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this series of blog posts](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Events+get+a+little+overhaul+%22).

In C# <4, it used simple delegate operations in `lock`s.

In C# 4+, it uses a fancier lock-free algorithm by calling `Interlocked.CompareExchange` in a loop; look at it in a decompiler for more detail.

If you're *sure* that your classes will *never* be used on multiple threads, you don't need any of that; you can simply use unsynchronized delegate arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, your blog is down.

Comment: Hah! Working fine now. I got Service Unavailable Error 503 about 3 mins ago.

Comment: I got that once myself, but it went away upon refresh.  Blame Google (I use blogspot)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's exactly what you are looking for, but this article shows some of the .NET internals of add remove handlers. (Also shows how to get and manipulate those handlers)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/308536/How-to-copy-event-handlers-from-one-control-to-ano

If you are trying to add some logic there, you may find the article interesting....