# Event add and remove implementation details

Tags: c#, performance, events

I'm developing on a application which has a lot of performance critial code. When looking at my code i noticed that i also have a lot of `+=` and `-=`on events with many invokations, so i ask myself ( and now you ) how `+=` and `-=`are implemented and how fast it is when have a lot of invokations.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484962/default-event-add-remove-implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Underlyingly, an event is a list of event delegates. Adding a new event is similar in performance to calling `List<T>.Add()` (which is generally O(1)), while removing a delegate is equivalent to `List<T>.Remove()`, which is O(n) where *n* is the number of delegates in the list.

(This dosen't necessarily mean that delegates are actually *implemented* with a `List<T>` under the covers, but the performance characteristics are the same.)

Comment: So actually a bad performance when i add and remove a lot of invokations each update.